# Nullify all inheritors of the root class on destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, sti

Given the following:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base; end
class Bar < Foo; end
class Baz < Foo; end
```

Is there a "Rails'y" way to nullify the foreign keys for all `Bar`s and `Baz`s when a class with `has_many :foos` is deleted? This doesn't seem to work:

```
class Quux < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :foos, dependent: :nullify
end
```

I realize I could do this in a before/after_destroy callback, but I was wondering if there's a more canonical way to do it. Thanks!

**UPDATE**

My current solutions:

```
class Quux < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_destroy :nullify_foos

  private

  def nullify_foos
    Foo.where(quux_id: id).update_all(quux_id: nil)
  end
end
```

or

```
# (results in two queries?)
class Quux < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bars, dependent: :nullify
  has_many :bazs, dependent: :nullify
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you meant was `:dependent => :destroy` in your has_many association.

`has_many :foos, dependent: :destroy`

This may end up calling `:nullify` on the back-end, but it will only do so when actually removing the data row isn't viable.

Referenced here:  http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

Comment: I want a guarantee from Rails that all `Foo`s will only be nullified though.

Comment: Actually, I think you're right, I'm not sure rails will follow the up the hierarchy tree the way you want it to.  You'll probably need to use a callback method to guarantee your results.  Test it out?  Now, I'm curious.

Comment: The way I'm imagining it, it wouldn't be going up the hierarchy, but rather going down to anything that inherits from it. Seems plausible given that Rails is already smart enough to implement STI.